# Javascript React: I am getting a message in the console that is saying my React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is the message I am getting in the browser console:
src/App.js
Line 41:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'handleBonusItem' and 'handleDiscount'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Here is my code:

APP.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BirdCard from "./components/BirdCard";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";
import bonusItems from "./data/bonusItems.js"

function App() {
  const [birdInCart, setBirdInCart] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [bonusItem, setBonusItem] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

  const addToCart = (bird) => {
    const birdCartItem = {
        id: Math.random(),
        name: bird.name,
        price: bird.amount,
        image: bird.image,
    };
    //setBirdInCart(birdInCart.push(birdCartItem)) - this is not going to work because the push method returns the new length of an array & not the update array. Instead I have to use the spread operator

    setBirdInCart([...birdInCart, birdCartItem]);
    setTotal(total + birdCartItem.price);
    console.log(birdInCart)
  }

  const handleDiscount = () => {
    let discount = 0
// have to set discount to zero so that the discount can be applied correctly
    let totalPrice = birdInCart.reduce((acc, bird) => acc + bird.price, 0)

    if (birdInCart.length >= 3) {
      discount = .10 * totalPrice
    }
    setTotal(totalPrice - discount);
  }

//use useEffect to update the discount whenever the birdInCart array changes
  useEffect(() => {
    handleDiscount();
    handleBonusItem();
  }, [birdInCart, total]);

  const handleBonusItem = () => {
    let updatedMessage = "";
  
    if (total >= 100 && total < 300) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice(0, 1));
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following item: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else if (total >= 300 && total < 500) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice(0, 2));
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following items: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else if (total >= 500 && total < 1000) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice(0, 3));
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following items: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else if (total >= 1000) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice());
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following items: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else {
      updatedMessage = "Make a donation and receive a bonus item!";
    }
    console.log(bonusItem);
    console.log("hello")
    setMessage(updatedMessage);
  };

  // const removeFromCart = (bird) => {

  // }


  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Noni's Bird Sanctuary</h1>
      </header>
      <BirdCard 
        addToCart={addToCart}
        />
      <Cart 
        birdInCart={birdInCart} 
        total={total}
        message={message} 
        bonusItem={bonusItem}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Cart.js:

```
export default function Cart({ birdInCart, total, message, bonusItem }) {
    console.log(birdInCart);

    return (
        <div className="cart">
            <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
            <ol>
                {birdInCart?.map((bird)=> ( 
                    <li key={bird.id}>
                        <p>{bird.name}: {bird.price}</p>
                        <button type="button">Remove</button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ol>
            <h4>Cart Total: ${total}</h4>
            <p>{message}</p>
            <ul>
                {bonusItem?.map((item, i)=> (
                    <li key={i}>
                        {item}
                    </li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried adding more dependencies (handleDiscount, handleBonusItem) which turn the warning into an error. I want to remove the warning so that I can upload to Netlify with no problems. Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting when you include the function as dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You need add the two functions `handleBonusItem` and `handleDiscount` to the dependancies array. You also need to memoize the two functions using `useCallback`.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BirdCard from "./components/BirdCard";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";
import bonusItems from "./data/bonusItems.js"

function App() {
  const [birdInCart, setBirdInCart] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [bonusItem, setBonusItem] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

  const addToCart = (bird) => {
    const birdCartItem = {
        id: Math.random(),
        name: bird.name,
        price: bird.amount,
        image: bird.image,
    };
    //setBirdInCart(birdInCart.push(birdCartItem)) - this is not going to work because the push method returns the new length of an array & not the update array. Instead I have to use the spread operator

    setBirdInCart([...birdInCart, birdCartItem]);
    setTotal(total + birdCartItem.price);
    console.log(birdInCart)
  }

  const handleDiscount = useCallback(() => {
    let discount = 0
// have to set discount to zero so that the discount can be applied correctly
    let totalPrice = birdInCart.reduce((acc, bird) => acc + bird.price, 0)

    if (birdInCart.length >= 3) {
      discount = .10 * totalPrice
    }
    setTotal(totalPrice - discount);
  }, [birdInCart, setTotal]);

const handleBonusItem = useCallback(() => {
    let updatedMessage = "";
  
    if (total >= 100 && total < 300) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice(0, 1));
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following item: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else if (total >= 300 && total < 500) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice(0, 2));
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following items: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else if (total >= 500 && total < 1000) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice(0, 3));
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following items: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else if (total >= 1000) {
      setBonusItem(bonusItems.slice());
      updatedMessage = "Your donation has qualified you for the following items: ";
      console.log(bonusItem);
    } else {
      updatedMessage = "Make a donation and receive a bonus item!";
    }
    console.log(bonusItem);
    console.log("hello")
    setMessage(updatedMessage);
  }, [bonusItem, setBonusItem, setMessage]);

//use useEffect to update the discount whenever the birdInCart array changes
  useEffect(() => {
    handleDiscount();
    handleBonusItem();
  }, [birdInCart, total, handleDiscount, handleBonusItem]);

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Noni's Bird Sanctuary</h1>
      </header>
      <BirdCard 
        addToCart={addToCart}
        />
      <Cart 
        birdInCart={birdInCart} 
        total={total}
        message={message} 
        bonusItem={bonusItem}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```